# Recognized by Salesforce Trailhead :-)

Tags: discussion

Say no more, if only that was the right answer :-/

[image]

- to note, the correct answer is: 4 - TrailHead Help (If you wondered)

Comment: Um. What. Who do we talk to about fixing this quiz? Because the first place to look is the modules themselves. And the second place to look is ***the documentation***.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think that's a joke answer, actually :D

Comment: @AdrianLarson i've done a fair amount of work with the certification team and might be able to figure out who the right person is to get in contact, shoot me an email to ralph followed by that "a" symbol then "callaway" and a period than "cloud"

Answer (score 13):

I noticed this as well: https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/933484614412247040

I usually Google and then look for SFSE in the results as the first step.

Comment: You stole my words lol. That's what I do most of the time.